# Fix dependency resolution errors

Tags: dependencies, build.gradle, resolution

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kali_corporation.yogafitness"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

> [Blockquote][1]

    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'


    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.6.0'



    implementation 'com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.kaopiz:kprogresshud:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.2.1'
}
```

> Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-27.0.2-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-27.0.2-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-27.0.2-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-27.0.2-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-27.0.2-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-27.0.2-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-27.0.2-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-27.0.2-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-27.0.2-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-27.0.2-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2)
>
> Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

Comment: Welcome. I find question posts on stack**overflow** (**S**tack**E**xchange in general) work well when closing with an explicit question.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had also encountered the same issue (Fix dependency resolution errors) and the solution which worked for me was when I reduced

**compileSdkVersion** to 26

**buildToolsVersion**    to 28.0.3

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 26

    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.letsgo.wifitrigger"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 12
        versionName "1.2"
    }
```